# can we use subquery in .list() of a main query in QueryDSL?

Tags: querydsl

Here is the java code snippet what I am trying to do.

```
SQLQuery query1 = new SQLQuery(conn, configuration); 

SQLSubQuery sql = new SQLSubQuery().from(user).where(user.firstName.eq("Pradeep"));

List<List<String>> tupleList = query1.from(user).list(sql.list(user.firstName));
```

The last line is having a null pointer exception.

`with cause = null
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.mysema.query.sql.JavaTypeMapping.findType(JavaTypeMapping.java:129) ~[querydsl-sql-3.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mysema.query.sql.JavaTypeMapping.getType(JavaTypeMapping.java:108) ~[querydsl-sql-3.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mysema.query.sql.Configuration.getType(Configuration.java:316) ~[querydsl-sql-3.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mysema.query.sql.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:208) ~[querydsl-sql-3.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mysema.query.sql.AbstractSQLQuery.get(AbstractSQLQuery.java:111) ~[querydsl-sql-3.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mysema.query.sql.AbstractSQLQuery.list(AbstractSQLQuery.java:347) ~[querydsl-sql-3.6.1.jar:na]`

Comment: could you provide the stacktrace of the NPE?

Comment: @TimoWestkämper thanks for your reply..stacktrace added.